# What is [ and ] in c#?

Tags: c#

What is the [ and ] in c#? what is it used for? what does it mean?

example

```
[DefaultValue(null)]
[JsonName("name")]
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        if (this.name == null)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is an [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw(VS.80).aspx). By themselves they do nothing at all, they just decorate code. But code can discover attributes and react to them at runtime.

Comment: Also used for arrays, indexes, pointers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx

Comment: @cofiem: That's called `indexer`

Comment: sometimes you see these with common reference as just "decorator" as in:  "Use a decorator like [Webmethod] on your method..."

Comment: "By themselves they do nothing at all": This is not completely correct. It is surely true for your own custom attributes, but not for certain built-in ones that affect the IL that is generated by the compiler (e.g. the `MethodImplAttribute`).

Comment: @0xA3: that is true. Although in a sense it's still true, as it's the compiler reacting to the attributes, the attribute itself isn't actually performing IL modifications, the compiler is.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it is a way to define Attributes on methods and classes. Attributes are like special comments except they get compiled into the dll and can be queried at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Those are used for attributes in C#, are in a way like java annotations. Attributes are used by reflection. Attributes are used to give metainformation.
You can check the following links:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/progcsharp/chapter/ch18.html
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/assemblies/article.php/c7009 to see how can used.

Answer (score 2):

Its called an attribute and is used to add metadata to your code.

Answer (score 1):

These are the characters for defining [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28VS.80%29.aspx) (similar to [annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) in Java).

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `]` are Square Brackets.  In your usage, they indicate an attribute.  When used in other contexts, they indicate some kind of indexing.

Examples

```
int[] intArray = new int[6]; //Initializes an array of 6 integers
intArray[0] = 1; //Assigns the value 1 to the first (zero-based) index of intArray

string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;
//The above uses "text indexing" to find the connection string in your App.config
//   or Web.config with a key with the provided string (in this case "default")
```

You can also use square brakets to grab Dictionary items by Key name, elements in collections such as datasets either by index number, or name, etc.